# is any way to show empty paths in Dired like com/domain/example/database as single item?

Tags: dired

for example, Java/Scala sources have a convention that packages like `com.domain.example.database` should be represented as `com/domain/example/database` folder structure (and all dirs are empty except last one the `database`). So I wish to show deep paths like this as a single item as Github does. The `com/domain/example/database` should be shown as a single folder item at Dired.

As an example on Github see https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/modules/analysis-common/src/main - that folder has a `java/org/elasticsearch/analysis/common` and if you click on it, the `common` be opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is dired-collapse https://github.com/Fuco1/dired-hacks#dired-collapse which looks like the feature you search for.

Comment: thanks, it extracts that I'm looked for and it also works fine with dired-subtree together